# My IntelliJ had maven prob about package(folder)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, package

[screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2ug6.png)

IJ recognizes main.java as a package, not a normal folder.
This is maven project.
How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrectly marked `src` as a source root (notice that is is blue) - right click and "unmark" it as a source root.

Then, locate the `src\main\java` folder and right click on the `java` folder -> mark as source root.

Once you have done this, intellij should recognise your folder structure correctly.

You might also want to mark `resources` as a resource root.